# Highlight, count and delete overlapping point locations from different CSV layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, csv

I have many CSV file layers in my project in QGIS, and quite a few layers have points which share the same location. Is there a way I can compare, count and highlight those "duplicates" and then delete directly by selection. I could potentially do a workaround by first creating polygon layers first via buffering each point and then intersect the point layers.

I just wonder, as I remember there is a quite easy option in ArcGIS's spatial analyst where you can do so, I think.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you had a look at `select by location`?

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for... ;-P

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found a solution. I used the following tool:

Processing Toolbox --> QGIS geoalgorithms --> Vector selection tools --> Extract by location ( to create new layer with all overlapping points using intersects, overlaps and within as Geometric predicate and a precision of 0.2 for my all US data sets)

That new layer can then be used to count the overlapping locations or to delete them then from another layer. You can run also the Select by location tool, to just select the overlapping point and then remove them in the selected layer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it. 
I suggest you Group Stats, it is a [plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/)

It will help you to query out those duplicates